# How can I create an Android login page that will connect to an Oracle database?

Tags: android, database, oracle, mobile

I would like to create a login page that allows the user to enter a username and password, then connect to an Oracle database to authenticate the user and provide a login successful/unsuccessful.

Basically, how can I do this? What are the steps that the app will NEED to take to achieve this? Is there a tutorial online?

Comment: You (almost) never want users to connect directly to a database that you are hosting. Why do you want to do this? It's better that you create a facade that they connect to.

Comment: @Kaj Well I want to eventually provide an interface that they can access and use. However, the users will need to login in before they can use the interface, so I assume the app would need to connect to the database to verify login details.

Comment: How many users do you expect to have? You don't normally create one database user per external user. It's better to let the facade have a connection pool towards the database. All connections in the pool are using the same database user. You do instead verify your users by having a function in the facade. That function could check username/password against a database table (where you e.g. store a hash of the password)

Comment: @Kaj Sorry, I obviously got confused; that is what I meant I would like the app to check the username and password to verify the user. And THEN give them access to information within the database.

Comment: What you in that case want to do is to create something on the server side (the facade) and that isn't really related to Android development. You could create a set of jsp/servlets that return JSON result when the user is invoking them with parameters.

Answer (score -1):

You could follow a tutorial like this:

http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/8339-connect-android-mysql-database-tutorial.html

This shows how to extract data from a MySQL database into android. I think it could help you to get the answer you are looking for with an Oracle database.